# firebase errorCodes won't show up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to set up error codes to a login that for example a user wants to enter his profile but types in a wrong password, he'll get notified that he entered a wrong password... but if I try it it just brings me to the normal feed page without being logged in so the errorCode doesn't even show up...

```
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "")
            if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                switch errorCode {
                case .invalidEmail:
                    print("invalid email")
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Email is invalid", message: "Use upper and lower characters along with numbers", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
                    print("wrong credential")
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Information", message: "The Account exists with different Credentials than entered from you", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                case .wrongPassword:
                    print("wrong password")
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Password is wrong", message: "Please enter the correct password for your account", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                default:
                    print("Other error!")
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Ouhhhh", message: "It seems like something went wrong. Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
            return
        } else {
        //successfully logged in our user
        self.messagesController?.fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitle()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showJobs", sender: nil)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }})
```

Can anyone help me with this? it seems a bit like there were a few changes since firebase 5 but I didn't found anything about that

Comment: Does it print anything here? `print(error ?? "")`

Comment: yes, but instead of getting a alert I just get presented to the second vc

Comment: It means it doesn't go into the if condition. And if you print `AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code)`do you have anything? If it prints an array for example, it means that you need to loop into the array to find a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Get error codes properly**

In order to get error code properly you need to convert Swift **Error** to **NSError**.

You can use below code:

```
if error != nil {
     let ns_error = error! as NSError
     print(ns_error.code)
}
```

**2. Do UI related tasks on the completion block on Main Thread**

```
case .invalidEmail:
    print("invalid email")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // Update UI elements here
               let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Email is invalid", message: "Use upper and lower characters along with numbers", preferredStyle: .alert)
               alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                   alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
               }))
               self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

You need to handle all alerts and UI related cases in main thread.

**Try adding delay before presenting alert**

```
func delayExecution(seconds delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

Comment: ok nice, thank you, I understand now what my problem was, but sadly im getting **AlertController is not in the window hierarchy** as an error... I read something that I need to call the alert in the viewDidLoad but how should I do it in my situation?

Comment: Are you handling this SignIn logic in ViewDidLoad() ?

Comment: no, I do it when I a button is pressed... When I call the function in the viewDidLoad I get all the Alerts instantly when the view appears

Comment: Try adding delay of 1-3 seconds before presenting an alert to see if it works. I’ve updated the answer with delay function that you can use.

Comment: added it but nothing changed :/ same error as before with the window hierarchy